# Python matlibplot: visualizing a matrix of integers (-1, 0 or 1) with circles (same radius, different color)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a square matrix filled by -1, 0 or 1. I would like to visualize this matrix with spheres or circles of the same radius. Radius, indeed is not important at all. Those circles though, must have a different colour according to the number of the matrix cell.

For example: 
10 x 10 matrix -> 100 circles on a plane, 10 rows x 10 columns
Color of circle in position (2,9) depending on number of matrix in position (2,9).

Thank you!

People I know told me to use matlibplot, but I am new to Python and 
I have many issues!

This is what I did up to now:
{`

```
import numpy as np
#from implementations import *
#from config import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, -1, -1,-1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, -1, -1,-1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, -1, -1,-1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
])

rows=len(A) # finding number rows of lattice, so no need to worry about it!
columns=len(A[0]) # finding number columns of lattice, so no need to worry about it!

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(rows):
      for j in range(columns):
          if A[i][j]==-1:
              circle1 = plt.Circle((i*4, j*4), 2, color='blue')
              fig = plt.gcf()
              ax = fig.gca()
              ax.add_artist(circle1)
          if A[i][j]== 1:
              circle2 = plt.Circle((i*4, j*4), 2, color='yellow')
              fig = plt.gcf()
              ax = fig.gca()
              ax.add_artist(circle2)
      `}
```

Comment: It seems this can easily be done with a scatterplot ([`ax.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter)). Have you tried that doing something like that, where `x` and `y` represent the position of the circle on your plot, and your matrix of `-1, 0, 1` would be the colour. I suggest you try that and come back with a question if it doesn't work

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please take the time to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I tried to implement it this way.

Comment: Sorry guys. I edited my question to show you what I did. Please evaluate it now. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry guys. I edited my question to show you what I did. Please evaluate it now. Cheers! @tmdavison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the `matplotlib` code that uses [scatter matrix](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter):

```
# Imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import chain

# Create plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# Here is our matrix. Note, that it is expected to be rectangular!
matrix = [
    [0, 1, 0,1],
    [-1,1, 0,0],
    [1,-1,-1,1],
]

# Get X-length
X = len(matrix[0])

# Get Y-length
Y = len(matrix)

# Construct grids for scatter
x_grid = list(range(X)) * Y  # 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4...
y_grid = [y for y in range(Y) for _ in range(X)]  # 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2...

# Flatten the matrix because ax.scatter uses flat arrays
matrix_grid = list(chain(*matrix))

plt.scatter(
    x_grid,              # X-grid array of coordinates
    y_grid,              # Y-grid array of coordinates
    c=matrix_grid,       # Our flatten matrix of -1/0/1s
    cmap='gist_rainbow'  # Color map - defines colors
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One last question: do you know how to make radii of the circles bigger? I need to have them all tangent to each other (touching but not overlapping).

Comment: Look at 's' parameter in the link. It sets nodes size. I am not near PC now and can't write the code, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use a scatter as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, -1, -1,-1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, -1, -1,-1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 2, -1, -1,-1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
])

X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(A.shape[1]), np.arange(A.shape[0]))
plt.scatter(X.flatten(), Y.flatten(), c=A.flatten())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This would be perfect if first, the circles could be tangent to each other, second, if we could add a background color to the plot (like, for instance, red).

Comment: As you can see from the plot, the circles could only ever be tangent to each other in y direction. Is that what you mean? The axes background can be set via `ax.set_facecolor("red")`.